# Java swing components keep size (static)

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, window, jlist

I've got a problem with the size of some object, for example a JList. If I add a element, the size of the list will grow. Well that is good, but if I add alot of elements, the JList will be out of the window of my app and I can't see the bottom of it(Sorry for bad grammar). How can I can I make the size static, that it will not go 'under' my window size.

Mathijs

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you posted some code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add your list to `JScrollPane` then scroll pane to your panel as follows:

```
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(yourJList, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
yourPanel.add(scrollPane);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gone rebuild my layout and test it directly! Thanks! (I can't vote you up because I don't have enough points)